# how to initialize a form created with designer in delphi?

Tags: forms, delphi

how to initialize a form if for example i have one form created with designer and i want a second form that would be seperate but work as my full screen. the second form also has parameters that i want to write to but i get access violation.

Im currently trying to access these second form variables in first form's formcreate method. but like i said i get access violation so im guessing i need to initialize the second form to access variables in that form but i dont know how to do it, and where is the appriopriate way to do it

Comment: Do you want to dynamically create and display a form which you have designed in the IDE? If so, do you want to display it modally or non-modally?

Comment: i have one form that is my application and i made full screen output form that is seperate form. i need to initialize the second form because i cant reach the the variables that are located in the second form (access violation) i dont know where i need to initialize it and how exactly i should do it

Comment: so far ive done this ```Form:= TForm.CREATE(nil);``` but it does not seem right. and do i even need to do this for designer created forms?

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius you need to Create()` the *derived* form that you designed, not create `TForm` itself, which is a blank base class. `Form := TMyFullScreenOutputForm.Create(nil);` (use whatever you actually named it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You should not have one form's initialization be dependent on another form's existence. You should do one of three things:

1) (Preferred) Move the fields out from TForm2 to a non-form CLASS defined in a UNIT that you include in both Form1.PAS and Form2.PAS, and that you then create from within your TForm1.FormCreate

2) (Only if you can't do 1) Delay accessing Form2's fields until Form1's OnActivate, and ensure that OnActivate is only called once:

```
PROCEDURE TForm1.OnActivate(Sender : TObject);
  BEGIN
    OnActivate:=NIL;
    <Access Form2.Field>
  END;
```

3) (Only if 1 or 2 is undoable) Instantiate Form2 wihtin Form1's FormCreate (and remove it from auto-created forms):

```
PROCEDURE TForm1.FormCreate(Sender : TObject);
  BEGIN
    Application.CreateForm(Form2,TForm2); // Or Form2:=TForm2.Create(Application);
    <Access Form2.Field>
  END;
```

Of these three options, 1) is absolutely preferable...

Comment: if i call for example TForm2.create it will be the default  constructor?

Comment: You should not call a TForm's default (parameterless) constructor.

Comment: i kinda need to depend on other forms existence. I know what you mean but the form2 is my full screen output. thanks for the answers though ill use the third one because the application is really small and im not going to extend it.